# Linking Excel to Inventor

Tags: excel, vba

I have programmed macros in Excel and just tried linking the file to Inventor. I am only able to link .xls and .xlsx. The macro-enabled Excel file that I am trying to link can only be saved as a .xlsm. When  I try linking it using the all files option `(*.*)`, I am not able to choose the start cell which tells Inventor where to start pulling parameter values from the Excel sheet.

Am I able to link the .xlsm file another way?

Comment: Question is about Autodesk Inventor?

Comment: Could you be satisfied with a rule that read the Excel File?

Answer (score 0):

Once the file is linked open the parameters menu and find the linked file. right click on that and you should see an option to change the starting cell.

Comment: Please post your thoughts as a comment. This is not a complete answer. More can be found here. [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Inuka: This wouldn't be a good comment even if andrew had 50 rep, as it's a *partial answer*, not e.g. debugging tips or a request for key info.

Comment: @NathanTuggy yes I see at least he's trying to give something back to the  OP to try. Its a partial answer as you said but some one might find it helpful in future.

Comment: @Inuka: Standard practice for partial answers is to leave them that way until they can be expanded upon or referenced. As long as it's an *answer* in its own right to at least *part* of the question being asked, it's an answer.

Comment: @NathanTuggy thank you for your clarification. I will improve my future reviews accordingly. :)